# What causes a function to run in the console but not when it is invoked by an event listener?

Tags: javascript, console, html5-canvas

*EDIT*
Added a link to a sandbox with working code. For some reason it seems to be working in the sandbox in the same browser it wont work on?!?!

[CodeSandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-cartwright-5e8i4?file=/index.html)

I am experiencing this weird issue of invoking a function in the console and it working as expected. However, when I invoke the function via an event listener it breaks the element.

The element is a canvas that is drawing different "bodies" on to it over a set interval.

Why would cause this function to work in the console but not in the document?

[image]

Comment: It would help much to see a code snippet. You could upload it to codesandbox.

Comment: I have tried different browsers, incognito mode, different computers and can't seem to isolate the issue. I have changed the function to just add random planets instead of from the inputs. So baffled on the issue.

Comment: What you've put on CodeSandbox works on Chrome. Might it be that #color is not a string, but it would show in linter?

Comment: Also, might it be the case that Add planet fired twice? I noticed that if I call it two times inside event listener bug happens.

Comment: @radulle when I checked the type of each value being passed to the function, the color shows type of string. That was what I thought as well, that maybe the color picker value does not get passed as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Two questions and then I might be able to help you.

Number 1: Are you using a library like [p5.js](https://p5js.org) or are you drawing it straight onto the canvas?

Number 2: Could you please post the code, as there might be an error?

Also if you want a quick solution, try using a different browser (although this might not be the solution, it is worth a try), such as [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), or just regular [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/).

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: No libraries, just straight canvas and JavaScript. Shared a sandbox of the code but it seems to be working there. Now I am wonder if it has something to do with the inputs I am using on the actual project.

Comment: Really sorry, I think it is just a bug with whatever you are using. I can't help you. :(